# Cannot find class 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaStorageHandler'

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-kafka

Error Log:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Cannot find class 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaStorageHandler'
```

I've already add `/KAFKA_HOME/libs/*` to classpath

This is my test code:

```
(ID_code string, 
target int ,
var_0 FLOAT, 
var_1 FLOAT,
var_2 FLOAT,
var_3 FLOAT,
var_4 FLOAT)

STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaStorageHandler'

TBLPROPERTIES(
"kafka.topic" = "test_steam",
"kafka.bootstrap.servers" = "lcoal:8778");
```

I guess I'm missing some jar file. But I have trouble looking up KafkaStorageHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found there is a jar I should download and put into the $HIVE_HOME/lib folder : 
[kafka-handler-3.1.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/kafka-handler)
After that, hive worked with kafka.

Comment: but it would turn out `Error running query: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/DefaultHiveMetaHook
`

Comment: @DennisLi Did you find the solution for this? I had the same problem.